# CalDAV: Deleting entry by attribute or UID

Tags: linux, bulk, caldav

I am a network admin not a software developer and confronted with the following issue:
A user has five (here SOGo) CalDAV calendars and "Outlook CalDAV Synchronizer" has distributed all events homogenize over all calendars.
Creating an export/backup of one duplicate item reveals that "Outlook Synchronizer" adds special attributes to the not wanted duplicate entries that the original entry does not have like:

```
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
TZNAME:Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
```

Is there a way to delete all calendar entries containing i.e. the X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS attribute? With sogo-tools backup I can identify and create the according ics file but I don't know how to use it for deleting the according entry in the calendar.
I took a look into
https://github.com/wvrzel/simpleCalDAV/blob/master/example%20code/example.php
but have no idea how to convert these examples into a working script. Perhaps there are possibilities at a "higher level" to solve this problem?